# How to submit a bug/fix for jquery unobtrusive validation?

Tags: javascript, bug, jquery

I found a small bug in the microsoft mvc3 remote validation, concerning the clientside javascript implemented in jquerys unobtrusive javascript.

The problem/bug can be fixed by adding a few lines to jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js which is bundled in the microsoft mvc3 installation.

I can't seem to find a bug repository on jquery.com or in its plugins area. Am i not seeing the tree in the forest, or am i not going insane - where should i go with this problem - i already have the fix ready, but i'm afraid the next time jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js is updated (new version) and it's being applied to my project, my fix is overwritten.

I also fooled around with adding some javascript that replaces the adapter (that has the bug) with my own version after jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js has been loaded - the problem is, that it's pretty ugly and

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is a bug tracker for jQuery Core is located at: http://bugs.jquery.com

But given a quick search on the topic, jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js sounds like a jQuery plugin developed by Microsoft and should likely be reported to them.

Comment: There is a JQuery plugin for validation--but it's not the one included with ASP.NET MVC.  That's an MVC extension, and I can only assume you have to submit the bug report through the MVC team.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense to report it to MS - i wonder how i do that, but i guess i can find out :P

Comment: I stumbled across http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio but I'm not sure if that would be the correct place or not. (Admittedly I don't deal too much with Microsoft currently :) )